# Conditionally selecting variables in select statement

Tags: sql-server, case

I am trying to figure out if I should be using a case, or sub query, or something else for the following.

In a select statement, I want to select either variable X or variable Y based on the value of @Z.

If @Z is NULL, select @X from #table.

If @Z IS NOT NULL, select @Y from #table.

Example code, which I thought would work, but I don't think I have it right.

**Specific code:**

```
    case when @GroupCode is NULL
    THEN TP.ProductID ELSE NULL END,
    case when @GroupCode is not NULL
    THEN TP.GroupCode ELSE NULL END,
```

Full code

```
 SELECT
        T.TreatmentID,
        T.SamplingRandomNumber, 
        T.Stage,
        TreatmentOrdinal,
        case when @GroupCode is NULL
        THEN TP.ProductID ELSE NULL END,
        case when @GroupCode is not NULL
        THEN TP.GroupCode ELSE NULL END,
        CASE WHEN E.GroupPricing = 1 THEN TP.GroupCode ELSE 0 END AS OptimizationGroupID,
        @moneyZero AS Revenue,
        TP.CalculatedFrom,
        EG.Description,
        E.GroupPricing,
        TP.CurrencyCode
        ,
        TIP.*
    INTO #TreatmentDetails
    FROM AnalyticsDW.Treatment T
        INNER JOIN AnalyticsDW.TreatmentProduct TP ON T.TreatmentID = TP.TreatmentID 
        INNER JOIN AnalyticsDW.Product           P ON TP.ProductID  = P.ProductID
        LEFT JOIN  #t TIP on TIP.TreatmentID2=T.TreatmentID
        LEFT JOIN AnalyticsDW.ExperimentGroup   EG ON TP.GroupCode  = EG.ExperimentGroupCode
        LEFT JOIN AnalyticsDW.Experiment         E ON TP.GroupCode  = E.ExperimentGroupCode
             AND P.ProviderCode         = E.ProviderCode
             AND P.ProductCode          = E.ProductCode
             AND P.ClientCode           = E.ClientCode
             AND P.ProductVariationCode = E.ProductVariationCode
    WHERE 
    T.LoggedUTC BETWEEN @fromDate AND @toDate
    AND 
      T.Stage IN (0,1)
    AND 
     --TP.TreatmentID=13
    TP.TreatmentID BETWEEN @MinTreatmentID AND @MaxTreatmentID
    AND   P.ClientCode       = @ClientCode
    AND   (@provider         IS NULL OR P.ProviderCode          = @provider)
    AND   (@product          IS NULL OR P.ProductCode           = @product)
    AND   (@productVariation IS NULL OR P.ProductVariationCode  = @productVariation)
    AND   (@GroupCode        IS NULL OR TP.GroupCode            = @GroupCode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!

```
case when @GroupCode is NULL
    THEN TP.ProductID
    ELSE TP.GroupCode
END AS SomeFieldname
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this will work for this case. I think later in the query I will need cases where there are multiple fields that I will need in the select clause based on the value of GroupCode. Would this work in that case? Ie lets say if Groupcode is NULL, I would need TP. ProductID, TP.ProductID2, TP.ProductID3.

Comment: Probably will - go here and look at the first variation of CASE. Sounds like exactly what you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx